# Delete entire row based on specific word in the text

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have a worksheet that has this range

```
For Row = 1 To me.Rows.Count
    If xlWsheet5.Range("C" & row).Value = "France" Then
        xlWsheet5.Range("C" & row).EntireRow.Delete()
    End If
Next
```

The range C contains a text like this : "This is France"

Once the word "France" is detected, then delete the entire row

I tried the above code but it did not work

Note : Im using vb.net please if possible , post vb.net solution

Comment: "It did not work" is not a helpful error message. Please be more specific.

Comment: you code you provided i had to take off the Str to make it work .  but my other problem once the row is deleted it does not shift up .  i tried this xlWsheet2.Range("C" & row).EntireRow.Delete(Excel.XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp)

Answer (score -1):

Try changing:

```
If xlWsheet5.Range("C" & row).Value = "France" Then
```

to:

```
If InStr(xlWsheet5.Range("C" & row).Value,"France")>0 Then
```

The InStr method checks to see if the value appears in the cell or not irrelevant of what other text is in the cell.

**EDIT**

Comment: i tried that but i got an error ( can not convert it to numeric ) i had to delete  str and it worked great.                                                                                            how to shif up once you delete the row ? i tried this but did not work   xlWsheet2.Range("C" & row).EntireRow.Delete(Excel.XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp)